# Spec $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ in Mumford's Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Chapter II of Mumford's Red Book he discusses Spec $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and states that $V((p))$ is a copy of the affine line over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. How is this so? Here is what I understand so far:

$V((p))$ is the set of prime ideals (considered as points) that contain the principal ideal generated by $p$.

The prime ideals of the affine line over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ are the zero ideal and the principal ideals generated by the irreducible polynomials.

So what I take from this is that these two aforementioned sets of ideals are supposed to be the same (or isomorphic)? Can somebody please make this more concrete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$. Then the map
$$J \mapsto \{ a \in A : a + I \in J \}$$
defines a bijection between the ideals (resp. prime ideals) of the ring $A / I$ and the ideals (resp. prime ideals) of $A$ that contain $I$. This is straightforward commutative algebra.

In particular, there is a bijective correspondence between the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z} [X]$ that contain the principal ideal $(p)$ and the prime ideals of $\mathbb{F}_p [X]$. Actually, more is true: this is a homeomorphism between the closed subset $V ( (p) ) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z} [X]$ and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{F}_p [X]$. This is more or less what Mumford means.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you very much for your answer!